# how can I access ggplot stats

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to know if it's possible to access the results of `ggplot` command in a similar way to base graphics.
For a `boxplot` in base graphics I can access the `$stats` variable which gives the min, Q1, median etc

```
bp <- plot(ToothGrowth$supp, ToothGrowth$len)
str(bp)
## List of 6
##  $ stats: num [1:5, 1:2] 8.2 15.2 22.7 25.8 30.9 4.2 11.2 16.5 23.3 33.9
##  $ n    : num [1:2] 30 30
##  $ conf : num [1:2, 1:2] 19.6 25.8 13 20
##  $ out  : num(0) 
##  $ group: num(0) 
##  $ names: chr [1:2] "OJ" "VC"
```

Is there a similar way of getting the stats from the `ggplot2` equivalent command? I have looked but can't find any documentation about this. The output looks like:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggp <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=supp, y=len)) + geom_boxplot()
str(ggp)
## List of 9
##  $ data       :'data.frame': 60 obs. of  3 variables:
##   ..$ len : num [1:60] 4.2 11.5 7.3 5.8 6.4 10 11.2 11.2 5.2 7 ...
##   ..$ supp: Factor w/ 2 levels "OJ","VC": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
##   ..$ dose: num [1:60] 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 ...
##  $ layers     :List of 1
##   ..$ :Classes 'proto', 'environment' <environment: 0xc6cffd0> 
##  $ scales     :Reference class 'Scales' [package "ggplot2"] with 1 fields
##   ..$ scales: list()
##  ..and 21 methods, of which 9 are possibly relevant:
##  ..  add, clone, find, get_scales, has_scale, initialize, input, n, non_position_scales
##  $ mapping    :List of 2
##   ..$ x: symbol supp
##   ..$ y: symbol len
##  $ theme      : list()
##  $ coordinates:List of 1
##  ..$ limits:List of 2
##  .. ..$ x: NULL
##  .. ..$ y: NULL
##  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "cartesian" "coord"
## $ facet      :List of 1
##  ..$ shrink: logi TRUE
##  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "null" "facet"
## $ plot_env   :<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
## $ labels     :List of 2
##  ..$ x: chr "supp"
##  ..$ y: chr "len"
## - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "gg" "ggplot"
```

Comment: Did you look at help for ggplot_build()?  I think it will extract values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ggplot2 has a method to look at how a plot was constructed. The command below gets you what you are looking for. If you leave out $data you will see all of the data that was used to construct the plot.

Example:

`p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + geom_boxplot()
     ggplot_build(p)$data`